# Rate of change of cone volume - partial differentiation

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

I am in the midst of confusion in regards of this question:

I have to find an expression for the differential *dV*, and hence ${\frac{dV}{dt}}$.

The ${\frac{dV}{dt}}$ part I know how to solve (shown at the bottom). But I don't know how to find the expression for *dV*.

The question is as follows:

The base radius r (*mm*) of a right circular cone increases at 40mm/s and its height h (*mm*) increases at 50mm/s. Given that the volume of such a cone is $$V = 1/3 \pi r^2 h$$
 Find an expression for the differential *dV*, and hence ${\frac{dV}{dt}}$.

This is what I have gotten so far:
$${\frac{dV}{dt}} = \frac{\partial V}{\partial r}{\frac{dr}{dt} + \frac{\partial V}{\partial h}{\frac{dh}{dt}}}$$

How do I find the expression for dV?

Help is greatly appreciated. Many thanks!

Comment: Are you asking how to calculate $\frac{\partial V}{\partial r}$ and $\frac{\partial V}{\partial h}$? It would help if you could give a particular indication of what you are getting stuck on.

Comment: @GeoffPointer I don't know how to find the expression for dV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for the differential of $V$. I believe the expression $dV$ you are looking for is: $dV = \frac {\partial V} {\partial r} dr + \frac {\partial V} {\partial h} dh = (2/3 \pi rh)dr + (1/3 \pi r^2)dh$.

The next step would be evaluating $\frac {dV} {dt} = (2/3 \pi rh) \frac {dr} {dt} + (1/3 \pi r^2) \frac {dh} {dt}$ by setting $\frac {dr} {dt} = 40$ and $\frac {dh} {dt} = 50$. Now you can plug in any r and h to find out the instantaneous rate of change of the volume at that particular r and h.

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly what I need!

Comment: Glad it helped. Here is a link that may help, too: [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative). See the section "The total derivative via differentials."